Because mi_card requires SDK version >=2.18.0 <3.5.0, version solving failed
https://i.sstatic.net/JWTz6f2C.png
https://i.sstatic.net/V7lRfath.png
I cloned github repository on my android studio but while installing dependencies it is showing error. The current Dart SDK version is 3.5.0.  Because mi_card requires SDK version >=2.18.0 <3.5.0, version solving failed
it should install the dependencies

You either need to upgrade the mi_card dependency so it will support Dart sdk 3.5.0 or downgrade your Dart sdk version to below 3.5.0

_ Use a Version Manager
Use fvm (Flutter Version Management): fvm is a tool that allows you to manage multiple versions of Flutter and Dart on your machine. With fvm, you can easily switch between Flutter versions and their corresponding Dart SDKs for different projects.
Install fvm by running dart pub global activate fvm.
Use fvm install  to install a specific Flutter version.
Run fvm use  to use that version in your project.
_ Modify the pubspec.yaml to change the Dart SDK constraint to allow for newer versions
environment:
sdk: ">=2.18.0 <4.0.0"

I agree with the principle argument here, but I would recommend using puro (https://puro.dev) instead of fvm.  Puro installs easier, is more efficient, and works more closely with the IDEs and the command shells.

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive
You have to use flutter version 3.22.3 or lower and it gonna be easier if you use FVM (or puro) like first answer said
